# Get all events from Asterisk 12

Tags: c#, asterisk

In my application I want to show a real time overview of all active calls on a asterisk server.

That's why I want to get all events (channel created/destroyed etc.) from Asterisk 12 server using the Asterisk 12 REST API (ARI).

When I connect to the websocket I only get events that are somehow targeted to my application that I specified in the initial call to "/ari/events" (in this case "hello").

```
$ wscat.py 'ws://localhost:8088/ari/events?app=hello&api_key=...'
```

How can I get all events (e.g. also information about new incoming calls)?

Or is there another possibility to get the desired information?

I am using AsterNET.ARI .NET Stasis Framework and the following code:

```
// Create a message client to receive events on
Client = new ARIClient(
    new StasisEndpoint(Host, Port, Username, Password),
    AppName
);
Client.Connect();
Client.OnChannelStateChangeEvent += Client_OnChannelStateChangeEvent;
```

The method `Client_OnChannelStateChangeEvent` is only called for calls that I have originated by my application using `Client.Channels.Originate(...)`.

Comment: I have not looked into your specific requirements to confirm this but from memory I believe one of the specific objectives of the REST interface was to limit the capabilities (in terms if what can be posted/returned) on a per user basis. As such, I believe you need to specifically enable/assign capabilities. Depending on your setup over there Asterisk 12 now allows a user account to be created independently from an extension for example. In turn this opened up the ability for you to assign a user to more than one extension which in turn should now allow ARI to access both extensions.

Comment: @Dennis, Please tell us if you reached to any conclusions, and provide a sample code if possible. Thanks.

Comment: @JalaliShakib I cannot help you. I did not get any further with this. Was not at the project anymore when suggestion from NetContstructor.com was posted.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Asterisk 13 Events REST API](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Events+REST+API) wiki page there is a boolean option `subscribeAll` since Asterisk version 13:

> subscribeAll: *boolean* - Subscribe to all Asterisk events. If
> provided, the applications listed will be subscribed to all events,
> effectively disabling the application specific subscriptions. Default
> is 'false'.

The current AsterNET.ARI library also supports this option in [ARIClient](https://github.com/skrusty/AsterNET.ARI/blob/master/AsterNET.ARI/ARIClient.cs) class constructor:

```
/// <summary>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="endPoint"></param>
/// <param name="application"></param>
/// <param name="subscribeAllEvents">Subscribe to all Asterisk events. If provided, the applications listed will be subscribed to all events, effectively disabling the application specific subscriptions.</param>
/// <param name="ssl">Enable SSL/TLS support for ARI connection</param>
public AriClient(
    StasisEndpoint endPoint,
    string application,
    bool subscribeAllEvents = false,
    bool ssl = false)
    // Use Default Middleware
    : this(new RestActionConsumer(endPoint), new WebSocketEventProducer(endPoint, application), application, subscribeAllEvents, ssl)
{
}
```

So, if you can upgrade your Asterisk server to Version 13 or newer, you will be able to use ARI to get all events by initializing the ARIClient connection with the `subscribeAll` option set to `true`.

Otherwise, if you cannot upgrade your Asterisk version, you can use [AsterNET](https://github.com/AsterNET/AsterNET) library *to show a real time overview of all active calls on a asterisk server* via the AMI interface by retrieving and analyzing AMI events. Minimal code snippet from [AsterNET.Test/Program.cs](https://github.com/AsterNET/AsterNET/blob/master/Asterisk.2013/Asterisk.NET.Test/Asterisk.NET.Test/Program.cs):

```
static void dam_Events(object sender, ManagerEvent e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}

manager = new ManagerConnection(ASTERISK_HOST, ASTERISK_PORT, ASTERISK_LOGINNAME, ASTERISK_LOGINPWD);
manager.UnhandledEvent += new EventHandler<ManagerEvent>(dam_Events);
```

You can read more about the Asterisk interfaces AMI/AGI/ARI and the differences between them on the [Asterisk REST Interface (ARI)](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29395573) wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AMI(manager interface)

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/asterisk+manager+events

Comment: Why you writing this text to my answer? i not understand what you need at all.